# Benchmark datasets to compare Data Envelopment Analysis (DEA) models

Tags: data-request

I'm studying the effects of some data transformations over the technical efficiencies resulting from a DEA model. To do that, I'm looking for a benchmark dataset which has at least three variables with fifty observations each.
In my research I found some datasets, as in [[1](https://deazone.com/en/resources/data-sets)], [[2](http://www.holger-scheel.de/doordea.htm)] and [[3](http://www.etm.pdx.edu/dea/dataset/default.htm)],
but all with broken links.

Does someone know some reference dataset to conduct experiments with DEA models?